# dojo: define module to load google maps api, (I am a bit lost)

Tags: google-maps, dojo

Somebody can explain how to define dojo module (define/require) to use google maps api.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

```
(function(){ 
    var callback = function(){},
        callbackName = 'gmapscallback'+(new Date()).getTime();
    window[callbackName] = callback;
    define(['http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=true&callback=' + callbackName], function(){
        return google.maps;
    });
})();
```

[src](http://jasonwyatt.tumblr.com/post/18015760792/google-maps-api-in-an-amd-module-requirejs-dojo)